# Redefine shorcuts in Skim

Tags: pdf, shortcuts

I am using SKIM for Mac to read PDFs and annotate. I wonder how can I change keyboard shortcuts, the one I need the most for marking text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) is rather insane.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? Did you try posting on the Skim mailing list? http://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/mailman/

Comment: On Mac you can set a key shortcut in System Preferences, the problem is that in Skim most useful shortcut are taken, so I have not really improved the situation. Until I get to remove some default key binding of Skim, for instance that for CMD+E

Answer (score 0):

got it to work in a roundabout way. Go to preferences > keyboard shortcuts > App Shortcuts > add skim > Under skim add "New Highlight" > assign key

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.